# pure sympy: "loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type Mul which has no callable log method"

Tags: python, typeerror, sympy, lambdify

I am confused by `sympy`. First some setup. I entered the following into a python console

```
>>> import sympy as smp
>>> x, y = smp.symbols('x y', real=True)
>>> f = smp.log(x) + y
```

followed by

```
>>> smp.lambdify(x, f)(1)
y
```

which makes sense to me.

Then I went on to enter

```
>>> smp.lambdify(y, f)(1)
AttributeError: 'Symbol' object has no attribute 'log'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "\<stdin\>", line 1, in \<module\>
File "\<lambdifygenerated-9\>", line 2, in \_lambdifygenerated
TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type Symbol which has no callable log method
```

I did not think much of it, because it is plausible to me that just entering 1 can break things. But then

```
>>> smp.lambdify(y, f)(smp.sympify(1))
AttributeError: 'Symbol' object has no attribute 'log'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "\<stdin\>", line 1, in \<module\>
File "\<lambdifygenerated-10\>", line 2, in \_lambdifygenerated
TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type Symbol which has no callable log method
```

and now I am confused over why not evaluating the logarithm breaks things. I will have a good time for the next few days if I can *successfully evaluate y at a number of my choosing and get a sympy object again*, so advice from someone who resolved this / found an *alternative way of achieving my goal* would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lambdify` is mainly used to retrieve numerical data. Essentially, that error is telling you that you should always lambdify your expressions by specifying the appropriate amount of free symbols. So, your expressions contains two symbols, `x, y`, and you should generate a numerical function using both symbols: `nf = lambdify([x, y], f)`, and then evaluate it as `nf(x, 0)`. This, again will raise an error, because you asked `lambdify` to generate a numerical function to be evaluated with Numpy, which doesn't support symbolic objects, like `x`. One way to solve it is to request `lambdify` to use SymPy as the evaluation module: `nf = lambdify([x, y], f, modules="sympy")`, and then evaluate it as `nf(x, 1)` to get `log(x) + 1`.

But, if you just want to get back a symbolic expression, then `lambdify` is overkill. Just substitute the numerical values into your symbolic expression. For example:

```py
f.subs(y, 1)
# out: log(x) + 1
```

Comment: Thank you! My code looks very clean now thanks to this :)

Answer (score 0):

To complement the other answer, I'll try to explain what happens with the `lambdify` and `symbols`.

`lambdify` of `smp.log(x) + y` creates a function like

```
 def f(x): 
     return np.log(x) + y
```

`f(1)` is then `np.log(1)+y`, where `y` is the globally defined symbol.

In the `f(y)` case, it's trying to evaluate `np.log(x) + 1`.  `np.log(x)` will be evaluated as `np.log(np.array(x))`.  `np.array(x)` will be an `object` dtype array.  `np.log` on an object dtype array tries to call a `.log` method for each element, hence the `no callable log method` error.

The same happens with `sin` and `exp`.  Operators like `+` and `*` don't give problems because symbols and numbers all have the corresponding `__add__` and `__mul__` methods.  In other works, math on object dtype arrays is hit-or-miss, ok for operators, seldom working for ufunc like `log`.

Comment: Thank you to you, too! I now get the the purposes and inner workings to the practically necessary extent.