# Sympy error: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type Float which has no callable log method

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I am trying to program the newtons method for a system of equations, in the function I find the derivatives using sympy, do this for all of the partial derivatives to two equations. I use lambdify so I can use the derivatives as a function.

```py
x = sp.Symbol('x')
y = sp.Symbol('y')
temp1 = sp.diff(eq_1(x,y,T),x)
eq_1_d1 = sp.lambdify([x,y,sp.Symbol('T')],temp1)
```

This lets me find the derivatives at a point once, but when the while loop has ran once, the second run gives me the error in title:

```py
    solution_list = []
    solution_list.append([np.array([x_0]),np.array([y_0])])
    x = solution_list[-1][0][0]
    y = solution_list[-1][1][0]
    eq_arr = np.array([[eq_1(x,y,T)],[eq_2(x,y,T)]])
    while (eq_arr[0] > k and eq_arr[1] > k) or (eq_arr[0] < -k and eq_arr[1] < -k):
        x = solution_list[-1][0][0]
        y = solution_list[-1][1][0]
        temp_vec = np.array([[x],[y]])
        J = np.array([[eq_1_d1(x,y,T),eq_1_d2(x,y,T)],[eq_2_d1(x,y,T),eq_2_d2(x,y,T)]])
        J_inverse = np.linalg.inv(J)
        temp_vec2 = temp_vec - J_inverse @ eq_arr
        solution_list.append(temp_vec2)
```

I checked with print statements, that the x and y get correct values from the solution list, if I copy the line that is supposed to not work, and just change the log there to sp.log, it gives me a correct float, however for some reason the thing does not work here with lambdify and i dont get why.
here is the whole function derivative that does not work if that matters:

```py
def _lambdifygenerated(x, y, T):
     return -1662.8*log(-0.03049 + (x - 0.03049)/y)/(x - y)**2 + 1662.8/(x - 0.03049)**2 + 1662.8/(y*(-0.03049 + (x - 0.03049)/y)*(x - y)) + 5.537*y/x**2 + 11.074/x**3
```

Comment: The same problem with lamdified log was asked yesterday https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75806663/pure-sympy-loop-of-ufunc-does-not-support-argument-0-of-type-mul-which-has-no

Comment: Good that you include the `generated`.  As you can see both `x` and `y` appear in the `log` (I don't see `T` anywhere).  If either is object dtype, you'll get this error.  An obvious reason for being object dtype is the inclusion of a `sympy` symbol or expression, but creating a "ragged" array can also do this.  You loop code is not reproducible, so I can't help you debug it.